# How to run array formulas on cloud excel _E1 office package

Tags: excel, vba

How to run array formulas on cloud `excel _E1` office package?

Is it supported? Can we run `vba` on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA is not supported on Excel Online but you can still use matrix functions like `MINVERSE()` or `MMULT()`. Just remember to end the input of your formula with `<shift><cntrl><enter>` to produce the curly braces around it:

[image]